# R/ggplot2: Issue with geom_line connecting 2 scatterplot datasets instead of using separate lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, geom

I have 2 simple scatterplot datasets that I combined, and the resulting graph (in ggplot2) is exactly what I want except for the lines connecting the data. I'm trying to make it so there are two separate dashed lines with two different colors, but right now messing around with geom_line I'm only getting one line that connects all of the datasets. Below I'll attach my code and my desired/current outcome for the graph. I appreciate any help!

```
dfplus<-data.frame(Mean=c(2.20e7,6.18e7,3.28e7,3.46e8,1.09e9),
               sd=c(0e0,1.05e8,4.45e7,2.26e7,0e0),Category=c("2","3","4","5","6"))
dfminus<-data.frame(Mean=c(1.86e7,3.92e6,1.30e7,8.10e7,3.20e8),
                   sd=c(0e0,5.28e6,2e7,1.41e7,0e0),Category=c("2","3","4","5","6"))

dat <- rbind(dfplus, dfminus)
dat$dataset <- factor(c(rep("dfplus", dim(dfplus)[1]), rep("dfminus", dim(dfminus)[1])))
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Category, y=Mean, color=dataset, line=dataset,group=1))+ 
scale_color_manual(values=c('#56B4E9','#E69F00'))+geom_point(size=5,shape=21,aes(color=dataset))+
theme_classic()+geom_line()
```

Here's my desired graph (made in MS paint, imagine the lines are dashed):
[image]
Here's my current graph:
[image]

Comment: Use group =dataset and not the 1

Comment: FYI, three ways to automatically assign `dataset` *programmatically* instead of having to do it manually: (1) `dat <- rbind(transform(dfplus, dataset="dfplus"), transform(...))`, a little cumbersome. (2) `dat <- dplyr::bind_rows(dataset::lst(dfplus, dfminus), .id="dataset")`. (3) `dat <- data.table::rbindlist(list(dfplus=dfplus, dfminus=dfminus), idcol="dataset")`.

Answer (score 3):

You were right there! Instead of `group = 1`, use `group = dataset`.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=Category, y=Mean, color=dataset, 
                line=dataset,group= dataset))+ 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#56B4E9','#E69F00'))+
  geom_point(size=5,shape=21,aes(color=dataset))+
  theme_classic()+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!